# Debugging with Resharper 9 and Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, resharper-9.0

I use the newest build of Resharper (9.3) and Resharper C++ with Visual Studio 2013.

Code editing, refactoring, ... works great. But if I try to debug the code, I get a weird error:

- an empty window with "Source not available. The current thread is not currently running code or the call stack could not be obtained".

which makes debugging quite difficult.

I think the problem is related to Resharper, because this problem did not occur before I installed Resharper nor does the problem occur if Resharper is disabled.

Is there a solution for this problem or another tool with similar capabilities that can be used instead?

Answer (score 0):

Latest version is 9.2 and the bug should be reported to jetbrains